# I am getting compilation error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FirefoxDriver to WebDriver"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am getting this error while running program

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from FirefoxDriver to WebDriver

```
at selenium.FirstSelenium.main(FirstSelenium.java:11)
```

1.I have extracted all selenium jar files (using version -3.141.59)

2.I have downloaded geckodriver and given path is correct(geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64)
3.Also Imported import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; and import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

still getting the error.

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstSelenium {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://yahoo.com");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a problem with your project [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) or suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

The easiest solution would be just changing this line:

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```

to this one

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

However I would recommend switching to a build/dependency management tool like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org). Even if you don't plan to use it later on you could at least use Maven to retrieve [selenium-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) jar along with all dependent jars.

1. Create [*pom.xml* file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) somewhere on your hard drive with the following content

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <properties>
           <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
           <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
       </properties>

       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
               <version>3.141.59</version>
           </dependency>

       </dependencies>

   </project>
   ```
2. Navigate to the folder where the *pom.xml* lives and execute the [dependency:copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) command

   ```
   mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
   ```
3. That's it, the correct set of .jar files will be downloaded to `target/dependency` folder

See [Selenium Webdriver Tutorial with JAVA: How to set up a TestNG maven based project from scratch](https://experitest.com/blogs/testng_framework_maven/) article for comprehensive instructions on how to properly set up the project allowing building and executing your test using Maven.